# FreeRadius authentication issue

Tags: centos, pptp, freeradius, pptpd

Having an odd issue with pptp and freeradiuss on CentOS 6.4 VPSs. I have 1 VPS as the main freeradius server. 2 other VPS are used to connect to via pptp using the remote freeradius to authenticate. 1 VPS is working fine, but the other one is giving the following when trying to connect:

```
rad_recv: Access-Request packet from host xxxxx port 49241, id=223, length=76
    Service-Type = Framed-User
    Framed-Protocol = PPP
    User-Name = "xxxxx"
    Calling-Station-Id = "xxxxx"
    NAS-IP-Address = xxxxx
    NAS-Port = 0
# Executing section authorize from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+group authorize {
++[preprocess] = ok
++[chap] = noop
++[mschap] = noop
++[digest] = noop
[suffix] Looking up realm "xxxxx" for User-Name = "xxxxx"
[suffix] No such realm "xxxxx"
++[suffix] = noop
[eap] No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
++[eap] = noop
[files] users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 172
++[files] = ok
[sql]   expand: %{User-Name} -> xxxxx
[sql] sql_set_user escaped user --> 'xxxxx'
rlm_sql (sql): Reserving sql socket id: 24
[sql]   expand: SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op           FROM radcheck           WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           ORDER BY id -> SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op           FROM radcheck           WHERE username = 'xxxxx'           ORDER BY id
[sql] User found in radcheck table
[sql]   expand: SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op           FROM radreply           WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           ORDER BY id -> SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op           FROM radreply           WHERE username = 'xxxxx'           ORDER BY id
[sql]   expand: SELECT groupname           FROM radusergroup           WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}'           ORDER BY priority -> SELECT groupname           FROM radusergroup           WHERE username = 'xxxxx'           ORDER BY priority
[sql]   expand: SELECT id, groupname, attribute,           Value, op           FROM radgroupcheck           WHERE groupname = '%{Sql-Group}'           ORDER BY id -> SELECT id, groupname, attribute,           Value, op           FROM radgroupcheck           WHERE groupname = 'basic'           ORDER BY id
[sql] User found in group basic
[sql]   expand: SELECT id, groupname, attribute,           value, op           FROM radgroupreply           WHERE groupname = '%{Sql-Group}'           ORDER BY id -> SELECT id, groupname, attribute,           value, op           FROM radgroupreply           WHERE groupname = 'basic'           ORDER BY id
rlm_sql (sql): Released sql socket id: 24
++[sql] = ok
++[expiration] = noop
++[logintime] = noop
[pap] No clear-text password in the request.  Not performing PAP.
++[pap] = noop
+} # group authorize = ok
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!    Replacing User-Password in config items with Cleartext-Password.     !!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!! Please update your configuration so that the "known good"               !!!
!!! clear text password is in Cleartext-Password, and not in User-Password. !!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
WARNING: Please update your configuration, and remove 'Auth-Type = Local'
WARNING: Use the PAP or CHAP modules instead.
No User-Password or CHAP-Password attribute in the request.
Cannot perform authentication.
Failed to authenticate the user.
Using Post-Auth-Type REJECT
# Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+group REJECT {
[attr_filter.access_reject]     expand: %{User-Name} -> xxxxx
attr_filter: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
++[attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
+} # group REJECT = updated
Delaying reject of request 7 for 1 seconds
Going to the next request
Waking up in 0.9 seconds.
Sending delayed reject for request 7
Sending Access-Reject of id 223 to xxxxx port 49241
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
Cleaning up request 7 ID 223 with timestamp +570
Ready to process requests.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this please?

User file:

```
#
# Default for PPP: dynamic IP address, PPP mode, VJ-compression.
# NOTE: we do not use Hint = "PPP", since PPP might also be auto-detected
#       by the terminal server in which case there may not be a "P" suffix.
#       The terminal server sends "Framed-Protocol = PPP" for auto PPP.
DEFAULT Framed-Protocol == PPP
        Framed-Protocol = PPP,
        Framed-Compression = Van-Jacobson-TCP-IP

#
# Default for CSLIP: dynamic IP address, SLIP mode, VJ-compression.
DEFAULT Hint == "CSLIP"
        Framed-Protocol = SLIP,
        Framed-Compression = Van-Jacobson-TCP-IP

#
# Default for SLIP: dynamic IP address, SLIP mode.
DEFAULT Hint == "SLIP"
        Framed-Protocol = SLIP
```

Comment: The first thing I would do is to deal with the warnings.

Comment: Seems request is matching DEFAULT entry in Users. File which is setting Auth-type local . Removing it will work

Comment: Thanks both for the replies. I will look at the warnings, but form my research, these are not showstoppers. I have added the Users file to the post (the parts that are un-commented).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No User-Password or CHAP-Password attribute in the request.

This why the request is failing, The request is not supplying any password!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I thought this, but have confirmed that the freeradius+pptp set up is working from another VPS so it is not the freeradius server side, just can't work out what the difference is on the other server. Any idea what might be wrong with the freeradiusclient/pptp set up on the second server?

Comment: Can you please post a debug from a working pptp authentication. Also which guide did you follow to set up pptp, please also give link to that?

Comment: I used: http://lintut.com/setup-pptp-to-authenticate-off-freeradius-on-centos-6-and-ubuntu-11-10/

Comment: Will update the post with a debug from a working authentication, thanks

Comment: Successful auth: http://pastebin.com/4Uch5eMA

Comment: Most probably you haven't included microsoft dictionary. **INCLUDE /etc/radiusclient/dictionary.microsoft** from the guide you sent. Can you check?

Comment: Yep, spot on! Can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much for taking the time to help.